# mcollective on windows with masterless puppet

Tags: windows, puppet, mcollective

I am an absolute newbie with mcollective/puppet. Trying to setup mcollective on windows environment with masterless puppet configuration. I have downloaded mco 2.8.3, setup ActiveMQ, configured the server/client nodes and able to see them all in "mco ping". I have also installed puppet 3.8.1 & also mcollective-puppet-agent from github and installed it as a plugin. I am able to see it in my plugin list. But how do I control the puppet agent with mco (for example apply a manifest using puppet apply)? When I try to do "mco puppet status" it says "No request sent, we did not discover any nodes." Do I need to make additional configurations?

```
C:\mcollective\bin>mco ping
SERVER1                                 time=1277.39 ms
SERVER2                                 time=1478.57 ms


---- ping statistics ----
2 replies max: 1478.57 min: 1277.39 avg: 1377.98

C:\mcollective\bin>mco inventory SERVER1
Inventory for SERVER1:

   Server Statistics:
                      Version: 2.8.3
                   Start Time: 2015-09-16 16:35:18 +0100
                  Config File: C:\mcollective\etc\server.cfg
                  Collectives: mcollective
              Main Collective: mcollective
                   Process ID: 5068
               Total Messages: 11
      Messages Passed Filters: 4
            Messages Filtered: 7
             Expired Messages: 0
                 Replies Sent: 3
         Total Processor Time: 0.671 seconds
                  System Time: 0.546 seconds

   Agents:
      discovery       rpcutil

   Data Plugins:
      agent           collective      fact
      fstat           puppet          resource

   Configuration Management Classes:
      No classes applied

   Facts:
      No facts known

C:\mcollective\bin>mco puppet status

No request sent, we did not discover any nodes.



Finished processing 0 / 0 hosts in 0.00 ms

C:\mcollective\bin>mco rpc puppet status
Discovering hosts using the mc method for 2 second(s) .... 0

No request sent, we did not discover any nodes.
```

Comment: you can see from the output that you supplied that the `mco puppet` agent is not there. Look under the `Agents:` section. You have the `puppet` data plugin. Either way. I think `puppet apply` might be outside the scope of typical `mco` usage without writing a custom agent, i may be wrong though.

Comment: thanks, yes, after the puppet installation it is listing under Data plugin and not under Agents plugin. I am not sure how would I configure it as data plugin.